# Angular can't use HttpClient in external library

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

When I try to instantiate the `HttpClient` service in an external library, then consume that library in an Angular application, I'm getting `StaticInjectorError` errors:

With **Angular 5.0.0**:

```
AppComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1 ERROR Error:
  StaticInjectorError[InjectionToken DocumentToken]:   
  StaticInjectorError[InjectionToken DocumentToken]: 
     NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken DocumentToken!
     at _NullInjector.get (core.js:993)
     at resolveToken (core.js:1281)
     at tryResolveToken (core.js:1223)
     at StaticInjector.get (core.js:1094)
     at resolveToken (core.js:1281)
     at tryResolveToken (core.js:1223)
     at StaticInjector.get (core.js:1094)
     at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:10878)
     at _createClass (core.js:10919)
     at _createProviderInstance$1 (core.js:10889)
```

With **Angular 5.2.0-rc.0**:

```
ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[HttpXsrfTokenExtractor ->
InjectionToken DocumentToken]:    StaticInjectorError(Platform:
core)[HttpXsrfTokenExtractor -> InjectionToken DocumentToken]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken DocumentToken!
    at _NullInjector.get (core.js:994)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1292)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1234)
    at StaticInjector.get (core.js:1102)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1292)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1234)
    at StaticInjector.get (core.js:1102)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:10836)
    at _createClass (core.js:10877)
    at _createProviderInstance$1 (core.js:10847)
```

I reproduced this with a blank `@angular/cli` application importing a blank library seed from [angular-library-starter](https://github.com/robisim74/angular-library-starter) which just imports and tries to use HttpClient:

(import lines truncated for brevity)

Application: `app.module.ts`:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  imports: [ ..., ArithmeticModule.forRoot() ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Application: `app.component.ts`:

```
@Component({
  ...
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private sum: SumService) {}
}
```

For the library, all I did was import `HttpClientModule` in the library module, and then try to inject it in `SumService`:

Library: `arithmetic.module.ts`:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [ HttpClientModule ]
})
export class ArithmeticModule {
    public static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
        return {
            ngModule: ArithmeticModule,
            providers: [ SumService ]
        };
    }
}
```

Library: `sum.service.ts`:

```
@Injectable()
export class SumService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
  ....
}
```

This setup causes the `StaticInjectorError` errors mentioned at the top of the post.

- In the rollup config, I've added `@angular/common/http`/`ng.common.http` as external/global.
- I've tried this with many different setups, library seeds, with rollup, and with webpack.  It all results in the same issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: HttpClient is defined in HttpClientModule.

Comment: Have you tried exporting `HttpClientModule` in the library module, too? What I like to do is make `@angular/common` a peer dependency, and let the hosting application handle the rest by importing `HttpClientModule` in the app-module and all that.

Comment: @R.Richards thanks for the suggestion, but it looks like that results in the same error for me.  I have `@angular/common` as a peer dependency, and marked as external in rollup/webpack.

Comment: Have you tried to `provide` the `SumService` in the *app.module.ts*?

Comment: Yes, that also does not fix the issue.  Regardless, `SumService` is provided in the library, and the library is imported, so I don't believe I'd ever have to directly provide the library service in the app itself.

Comment: I did just realize that this actually works in AoT, but not in JIT.  `ng serve` fails, but `ng serve --aot` does not.

Comment: any update @Mike ? did you resolve this issue ?

Comment: Yup. I've hit this problem too.  Any resolution?

Answer (score 1):

The way your are consuming the sum.service is just a sub module of the main module, which is your app.module.ts. The HttpClientModule will need to be imported into the app.module.ts to be consumed by any sub module.

The reason you don't get an error with AOT is because in that sense there is a different injector.

> In the app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ HttpClientModule ]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into similar problem and fixed upgrading the NgxMaskModule (2.2.2) and added the NgxMaskModule.forRoot() in the module import.

Comment: I'm sadly not using that module. But I may look at what they changed in their last update. Maybe that gives me some clues

Comment: Check the import order.  HttpModule must be imported before HttpClientModule.  Like:   imports: [  BrowserModule,  FormsModule,    HttpModule,   HttpClientModule  ]

Comment: That's the current order of my imports and the problem persists. I've tried different ways of sorting it but it does not really help.

Answer (score 0):

Try Importing **HttpClient** module in your **app.module.ts.**

**HttpClientModule** will be your peer dependency in this case,

so you have to import HttpClientModule in your main app.

Answer (score 0):

we are using HttpClient for translate module. I'm using importing way that below;

```
// translate
HttpClientModule,
TranslateModule.forRoot({
       loader: {
            provide: TranslateLoader,
            useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
            deps: [HttpClient]
        }
    }),
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem too and I got it fixed in this way:

add HttpClientTestingModule in TestBed configuration object

```
 beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule]
    });
  });
```

import it form

```
import { HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
```

Answer (score -1):

**StaticInjectorError**

Try like import HttpClient Module in module.ts and add the service to the providers might work.